# Unicode code point to utf8 and wctomb

Tags: c, linux, unicode, utf-8

I was looking for ways to convert unicode codepoints to utf8.
So far, I've learned I can do it manually or use iconv.

I also thought wctomb would work, but it doesn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define CENTER_UTF8 "\xf0\x9d\x8c\x86"
#define CENTER_UNICODE 0x1D306

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    puts(CENTER_UTF8); //OK
    static char buf[10];
    int r;

#define WCTOMB(What) \
    wctomb(NULL,0); \
    r=wctomb(buf,What); \
    puts(buf); \
    printf("r=%d\n", r);

    //Either one fails with -1
    WCTOMB(CENTER_UNICODE);
    WCTOMB(htonl(CENTER_UNICODE));
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why wctomb won't convert a unicode codepoint to utf8. I'm on Linux with a utf8 locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change program locale properly before using of `wctomb()`:

```
#include <locale.h>
/* ... */
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

This sets up program locale setting according to your environment. [man setlocale](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html)

> If locale is an empty string, "", each part of the locale that should
>   be modified is set according to the environment variables.

P.S. Actually `LC_CTYPE` is enough for `wctomb()`.

Comment: This works as long as the program is run in a UTF-8 locale, otherwise you'd need to replace the empty string in the call to `setlocale` with the name of an installed UTF-8 locale.